# File transfer - Bandwidth flickering for no reason

Tags: networking, performance, bandwidth, file-transfer, iperf

We are experiencing file transfer issues. I try to troubleshoot this problem but it is really hard.

Here is a screenshot I took while transferring a file from my workstation to another server. The screenshot was taken from the workstation (source):

- The whole graphic was taken during the file transfer, there was no pause on the transfer or anything.

[image]

It doesnt stop to flicker like this. And the ETA of the transfer always changes from 10 minutes to an hour or so, and then gets back to 9 minutes, then back to 100 minutes, so on so forth.

Here is the **iperf** result:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Possible network storm? Are your switches managed?

Comment: It isn't clear to me, is that graph from the server?

Comment: How big is the file?  Does it ever transfer successfully?  If so how long does it take?  The workstation and server are connected how?

Comment: There is only a single Dell PowerConnect 5324 (with the latest firmware version) between the two hosts. How can I diagnose if the switch is faulty?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wireshark` on the server and/or the client. I would guess there is a network congestion going on that forces down the sliding window TCP size of your transfers. Are all components connected with rx/tx flow control set to "on"?

Comment: How can I detect if my TCP size has been reduced due to network congestion?

Comment: If rx/tx flow control is on the corresponding counters should grow (on the switch/router and/or server side). There should also be a sliding window negotiation visible. [See the WiKi for details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sliding_window_protocol)

Answer (score 0):

It seems less likely to me that your problem would be a networking issue. I would consider an I/O bottleneck first. Check your server's disk idle time during the transfer and try to find possible interconnections with the drops in your transfer rate.

Comment: I think iperf.exe does not write anything on disks, it just tests the network bandwidth between two hosts, am I right?